# bokeh tooltips name with space or special char

Tags: python, tooltip, bokeh

my plot is showing ??? when I have space or special char on the column name.
here is my code :

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, ColumnDataSource
import pandas as pd

# prepare some data
xx = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
yy = [4, 5, 5, 7, 2]
df_xy = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(xx, yy)), columns=['name with space', 'y_y:y'])
#df_xy = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(xx, yy)), columns=['name', 'y'])
source = ColumnDataSource(df_xy)

pp = figure(y_range=(0, 10), sizing_mode="stretch_width", max_width=500, height=250,
    tooltips="@name with space has the value @y_y:y")
#    tooltips="@name has the value @y")

pp.circle(source.column_names[1], source.column_names[2], size=10, source=source)
pp.line(source.column_names[1], source.column_names[2], line_width=2, source=source)

# show the results
show(pp)
```

the df is like this

```
    name with space       y_y:y
0   1                     4
1   2                     5
2   3                     5
3   4                     7
4   5                     2
```

when I change the column name with regular name (no space, no spcial char) it works.

how can I make it work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `"@{name with space}` and `@{y_y:y}`

```py
tooltips="@{name with space} has the value @{y_y:y}"
```

---

**BTW:**

If you want to format then you can use another `{ }`

ie. `@{y_y:y}{0.00}` to get value with two digits after dot.

```py
tooltips="@{name with space} has the value @{y_y:y}{0.00}"
```

---

Example from older version 1.0.4 shows more - i.e multiline tooltip and `formatters`:

[tools_hover_tooltip_formatting.py](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/1.0.4/docs/user_guide/examples/tools_hover_tooltip_formatting.html)

---

Other information in the latest doc: [basic-tooltips](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#basic-tooltips)

Comment: Thank you. it works very well (y)